# Display labels with "selected" indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, durandal

I work in **durandal** project, and have html page with 3 label.
I want the label to behave like radio-buttons: When one is selected- other not selected.

I want that the labels will be gray, and the selected label (user select by click) will become black.

Of course, I can do it by jquery, like:

html:

```
 <label id="large" data-bind="click:change" style="color:Black">
 <label id="medium" data-bind="click:change" style="color:Gray">
 <label id="small" data-bind="click:change" style="color:Gray">
```

java-script:

```
 var selectedId = "large"; //global variable
 function change(e, s){
   $('#'+selectedId).css('color', 'Gray'); // change previous-selection to gray
   $('#'+sender.currentTarget.id).css('color', 'Black');// change current-selection to gray
   selectedId = sender.currentTarget.id;
 }
```

But, Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: Some one edited my post ans remove the question in the end.  I returned it; read it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them a common class such as ".labels" and wrap them, the html becomes :

```
 <div class="label-container">
    <label class="labels" id="large">large</label>
    <label class="labels" id="medium">medium</label>
    <label class="labels" id="small">small</label>
</div>
```

In your css define 2 classes, one with the active state (black):

```
.labels{
color:#ededed;
}

.active{
color:#000;
}
```

And your javascript/jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.labels', function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

And you're done. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqLbu/)
For a pure css solution refer to @gulty's answer.

Answer (score 2):

With pure css and hidden radio buttons:
http://jsfiddle.net/GFC2G/2/

```
input[type="radio"]{display:none}
input[type="radio"]+label{ 
    color:red;
   -webkit-transition:0.2s all linear;
   -moz-transition:0.2s all linear;
   -o-transition:0.2s all linear;
   transition:0.2s all linear;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ 
    color:black; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="rad"><label for="rad">Radio 1</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="rad"><label for="rad">Radio 2</label>
```

Comment: I like your answer, but the op doesn't seem to be using actual checkboxes ( not the one downvoting )

Comment: Just hide the checkboxes (Add to your post @gulty :) `input[type="radio"] { display: none; }` This is a neat answer.

Comment: he asked for a css solution 'Of course, I can do it by jquery, like:' and since he didn't provide more info on what kind of label he is using..

Comment: His jquery is horrible though

Comment: @gulty he doesn't want input, but `labels to behave like radio-buttons`

Comment: I agree, there is no reason to not have radio buttons apart from looks. For semantics radio buttons work best. For looks, hiding radio buttons works best. This is a good answer people.

Comment: I thouht people should actually be able to think. I gave a JS free hint - now I updated my post hiding the radio buttons. Doesn't change the fact this is working like a charm.

Comment: To avoid any more downvotes (this is the best answer IMO) state at the top of your post: "You don't want radio buttons? Is this just a looks thing? We can hide them to get the result you want". Or whatever :)

Comment: What kind of attitude? IMO stackoverflow is a plattform to help people getting a good approach for a problem. People shouldn't be here to expect a full solution. And if someone don't wanna have input radios just hide em..

Answer (score 1):

working code is below,this will work 100%
http://jsfiddle.net/bqLbu/1/

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>


    <script>

$(function () { 
$('label').click(function () { //when you will click on any label
var selectedId=$(this).attr('id');//get id of that label

   $('#'+selectedId).css('color', 'black'); // change selection to black

    $('label').not('#'+selectedId).css('color', 'grey');  //others to grey
 }); 
  });

 </script>


<label id="large" data-bind="click:change" style="color:green">hi22</label>
 <label id="medium" data-bind="click:change" style="color:green">hi 2342</label>
 <label id="small" data-bind="click:change" style="color:green">hi424</label>
```

Comment: 1. Event delegation.
2. No need to wrap this you can get the id attribute with vanilla js (this.id).
3. No need to apply the css via js.